# Column not found - Laravel whereHas error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a hard time resolving this error.

My models:

User Model:

```
class User extends Model{
    public function requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TeamRequest','requested_user_id');
    }
}
```

TeamRequest Model:

```
class TeamRequest extends Model {

    public function requested_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'requested_user_id');
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying this query:

```
UserModel::whereHas('requests',function($query) use ($team_id){
            $query->where('team_id',$team_id)
                    ->get();
        });
```

And, I'm getting an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause'
>   (SQL: select count(*) from `team_requests` where
>   `team_requests`.`requested_user_id` = `users`.`id`)

Why am I getting this error?

Schema:

users table

primary key - id

varchar - email

varchar - password

team_requests table

primary key - id

integer - requested_user_id

I have other columns but I believe they do are not of effect.

Comment: There, I added the schema

Comment: Actually, I am making a sort of friend request and accept type of application. So, this is what I used.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I tried but still got an error - unknown column `users.requested_user_id`

Comment: yes, that is what most amusing and irritating.

Comment: Same error. Looks like entire PHP is plotting against me. :/

Comment: Yes, that's a convention I use.

Comment: I did: `use App\Models\User as UserModel`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `get()` inside the closure passed to your `whereHas()`. The closure is used to add constraints to a subquery that will be used to determine if your user has requests. You're only supposed to add constraints to the query inside the closure, you don't want to actually execute that query. If you execute the query inside the closure, you'll get an error (as you've seen) because it is supposed to be a subquery, and does not have all the information required to execute properly.

Your code should be:

```
UserModel::whereHas('requests', function ($query) use ($team_id) {
    $query->where('team_id', $team_id);
});
```